# Android Sms Broadcast Receiver not firing despite priority

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have read many similar questions that usually results in an answer about priority. The reason I don't think this is true in my case is that other SMS readers on my phone (like automation apps) receive the broadcasts just fine. I would like to post the process of what I'm doing currently and make triple sure that I'm not doing something wrong in my code that would cause this to fail. Thanks for any tips you can give!

**Note:** I've tried with the highest integer priority, priority 99, 100, 0, or none set at all. They all don't work.

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hennessylabs.appname" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.hennessylabs.drivercompanion.ProcessTextMessage" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
package com.hennessylabs.appname;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by kyleC on 11/15/2015.
 */
public class ProcessTextMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Entered onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                    Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);


                    // Show alert
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "senderNum: " + senderNum + ", message: " + message, duration);
                    toast.show();

                } // end for loop
            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Result:**

The expected result is that when an SMS arrives, the screen would first show a Toast that it entered the OnReceive method. Then it would log and Toast the contents of the SMS.

**Actual Result:**

Nothing from the expected result happens. In fact even while connected to USB and in debug mode it never seems to enter that class at all. So maybe I have my manifest set up wrong?

Comment: can you try 9999 this number

Comment: @AmitBasliyal Same result

Comment: `<receiver android:name="SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>` my receiver is this   try this may be help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided everything else is correct, it looks like you're just missing the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some things from the manifest declaration of your receiver. You must declare `exported=true` and you must require the `BROADCAST_SMS` permission. See working example:

```
    <receiver android:name=".sms.IncomingSmsReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. I've updated my question with my new manifest. Unfortunately, I am getting the same result.

Comment: Neither of those things is a "must".

Answer (score 0):

So what is the version of the device your app is running on?

Begins in Android 4.4, only the default sms app can receive the SMS_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast.

more information: http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: 4.4.2 and up are the devices I'm targeting. Although that article specifically seems relevant to those who want to make a sms default app. I do not.

Comment: The OP is taking about the `SMS_RECEIVED` action, which all apps can still get, whether they're the default SMS app or not. That blog post explains it rather well.